# Removing trailing spaces in eclipse -- FROM THE COMMENTS

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, code-formatting

*Preferences -> Java -> Editors -> Save Actions Check "Perform the selected actions on save", then check "Additional actions" and click the "Configure.." button. In the "Code organizing" tab, check "Remove trailing whitespace"*

That will do the job for any normal code, however this does not look to have any effect on the comments. Is there any way to automatically get rid of trailing spaces from the commented lines?

Thanks,

p

Comment: Works as described on both single comment lines // and /* */. Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

Comment: Works for me too, Build id 20100917-0705.

Comment: Doesn't work form me, Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149

Comment: Doesn't work for javadoc comments, works for other comments

Comment: also having this issue, the problem is definitely the javadoc comments auto-inserting spaces, and then there is no way to auto-remove them.  Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: IIRC this issue has been annoying some (most?) Eclipse users for at least a decade.

Answer (score 3):

This is something i've tried to remove trailing space:

Window->Preferences 
Jave->Editor->Save Actions 
Enable Perform the selected actions on save. 
Enable Additional actions. 
Click Configure.

In the Code Organizing tab, 
enable Remove trailing whitespace for All lines. 
Review all the other options there, since it will all happen 
automatically whenever you save -- make sure there isn't anything 
there you don't want. 
Dismiss the Configure window.

Review the other options under Save Actions, since these will also happen automatically now. 
Don't forget to click Apply in the Save Actions preference page. it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've contracted same trouble recently and it seems impossible to handle within IDE without any external tools. This is what worked for me:

```
sed -i 's/\s\+$//' MyClass.java
```

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to format your code (and of course your comments/javadoc) is with a customized formatter. See Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter Button "Edit" => Tab "Comments", Option "Enable Javadoc formatting", etc.
and then to click "Format source code" as an automatically save action.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Ordinary comments were fixed, but javadocs stand still·